# Using WindowListener without making all the functions

Tags: java, mouselistener, windowlistener

I want to use a WindowAdapter and a MouseAdapter. This issue is that java only lets me use one of those. The other must be a WindowListener. The problem with that is that it requires me to use several functions that I don't use to do one thing. Is there a way I can use the WindowListener without making all the unnecessary functions?

Comment: There is not.  You will have to implement at least one of them as a Listener, and implement these interfaces fully (even if the said implementations are empty).

Answer (score 0):

Java allows classes to extend only one class. The canonical solution to this is to use anonymous or named inner classes for your listeners. Also you can use stand-alone classes that extend your listener adapters, all depending on your needs and uses.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own WindowAndMouseAdapter that extends WindowAdapter and implements MouseListener. Then you can capsulate the empty methods from listener implementation in this adapter, which keeps your business class more clean.